# Xbee compatibility Xbee-PRO

Tags: xbee, zigbee

is XBee-PRO 900 compatible with XBee-PRO 900HP (S3B) 10K?

Are in general Xbee modules compatible between families?
I tried to change firmware but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately they are not compatible with each other if they have different firmware. The XBP9B-DP 10K is going to speak a different over the air language than the XBP09-DP.

However, I have had success loading matching firmware into two different Xbees. In my case, the XBPB9B-XCWT and XBP9B-DMWT both loaded as XBP9B-DMWT. You may have to use the recovery procedure of the XCTU software to do this. Click the wrench icon (tools) and select 'Xbee recovery' from the drop down.

[image]